# Badge tracker for "custodian" links to the review page despite insufficient rep to review

Tags: bug, badge-progress

When tracking "custodian" badge with the new profile Badge Tracker function, the link "`Go get it >`" goes to the "Review" page.

However, on the sites I tested I cannot review *anything*.
So sending me to the review page is a *cheeky tease*, and *wrong* to do so as I cannot "Go get it" from the place I'm sent to as was suggested to me.

### Repro on multiple sites

I've tested and can repro on other sites, Main and Meta and betas.

Repro on:

1. Stack Overflow Main and Meta
2. Code Review Main and Meta
3. Server Fault Main and Meta

### Suggestion

Suggest removing "Custodian" badge from profile badge tracker when user does not have enough rep to review on the given site.

Comment: Reproduced on Stack Overflow Meta. "Custodian" is the default tracked badge for me, while I don't have enough rep to review any queue. Also, apart from "custodian", on SO Meta I can also choose to track "Informed", but SO Meta does not have its own Tour page and so it is impossible to get that badge.